# On executing python manage,py runserver is not showing any output on terminal

Tags: django, python-3.x

While executing **python manage.py runserver** is not showing any output on terminal and process exist without showing any error.

Don't know how to fix it ??. I am new to djano.

Comment: You probably need to check if there is some kind of logging defined in settings.py or how your wsgi is configured.

Comment: do you have this problem with any other new initialized projects in your computer? if yes, which version of python and django you are using? are you using virtual environment?
please post more information about your problem and if possible, some codes from your project such as settings.py

Comment: Yes, this problem persist even if I create a new django project python version 3.7.4, I am using Pycharm professional ide, so I don't need to create a new env for django project.